# SQL Query Python Variables

Tags: python, sql, postgis, qsqlquery

I'm trying to make a postgis query using python variables. However when i do the below query:

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM "12NM(LineGridExp)" WHERE "12NM(LineGridExp)".geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326)""",str(x0), str(y0), str(x1), str(y1)

TerrLine = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, connection, geom_col='geom')
```

i get the following:

```
 Execution failed on sql '('SELECT * FROM "12NM(LineGridExp)" WHERE "12NM(LineGridExp)".geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(%s, %s, %s, %s, 4326)', -1.400993559416539)': argument 1 must be a string or unicode object: got tuple instead
```

I must be missing something small but i cant seem to get it to work.

x0, y0, x1, y1 are all floats.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated,

Tom

Comment: Can you provide the variables themselves?

Answer (score 0):

You're not substituting the variables into the SQL string, you're setting `sql` to a tuple containing the SQL string followed by the variable values.

Assuming the PostGIS interface implements the standard `cursor` interface, you should give the variables as a tuple argument to `cursor.execute()` function.

```
sql = """SELECT * FROM "12NM(LineGridExp)" WHERE "12NM(LineGridExp)".geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326)"""
cur.execute(sql, (x0, y0, x1, y1))
```

Comment: Hi Barmar, it forms part of a geopandas query  `  sql = """SELECT * FROM "12NM(LineGridExp)" WHERE "12NM(LineGridExp)".geom && ST_MakeEnvelope(?, ?, ?, ?, 4326)""",str(x0), str(y0), str(x1), str(y1)
 TerrLine = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_postgis(sql, connection, geom_col='geom')` so the suggestions won't work like that i'm afraid.